# SSRS Hide/Show rows based on value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am making a SSRS that hide/show rows based on value. I have these data

```
Category         Offer        Revenue
Key Offer        Text 299     10
Change Plan      ALL-IN 1200  10
```

All I have is this expression in my details group

```
=IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Key Offer",true,false)
```

but when the report started the change Plan is displayed and Key Offer is hidden

[image]

What I want to happen is when the report start. Both "Key Offer" and "Change Plan" is hidden and when I click the drill button in then it will only display the data with `Category: Key Offer`

Comment: Can you provide more details for your report layout like if you have groups or only detail rows, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by setting the visibility on the group when initially run to hidden. Then below select the toggle. Then add a filter on the group to remove the category you do not want